# Why atleast a==b constraint not solved for the constraint solvers

Tags: system-verilog

I have a code that has a constraint

```
((((a == b) == c) == d) == e)
```

I can understand the values taken by c,d and e. But since `a == b` is a constraint here, why doesn't the solver solve for `a == b`? At least a and b should have same values.

```
module tb;
  class packet;
    rand bit [4:0] a,b,c,d,e;

  endclass

  initial
  begin
    packet pkt;
    pkt = new();
    if(pkt.randomize() with {pkt.a == pkt.b == pkt.c == pkt.d == pkt.e;})
      $display("a is %h, b is %h, c is %h,d is %h, e is %d \n", pkt.a, pkt.b, pkt.c, pkt.d, pkt.e);
    if(pkt.randomize() with {pkt.a == pkt.b == pkt.c;})
      $display("a is %h, b is %h, c is %h,d is %h \n", pkt.a, pkt.b, pkt.c, pkt.d);

  end  

endmodule
```

I get the output as

```
a is 00, b is 08, c is 1c,d is 00, e is  1 

a is 0d, b is 1d, c is 00,d is 09
```

I can relate the values taken by c,d and e. But, the values a and b I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer Verilog and SystemVerilog Gotchas: 101 Common Coding Errors by Stuart Sutherland and Don Mills. The listed book has covered the above gotcha and previous question Gotcha of fork-join_none.

Answer (score 5):

You have found a typical gotcha of SystemVerilog constraints let me explain,

"**==**" **is a binary operator which evaluates from left to right**

eg: **pkt.a==pkt.b**  - Here if **pkt.a** has same value of **pkt.b** then the result of evaluation is 1, otherwise result is 0

**(pkt.a==pkt.b)==pkt.c** - to make whole expression "true" **pkt.c** will have to be equal to result of **pkt.a==pkt.b** evaluation, meaning that if **pkt.a** is different from **pkt.b**, **pkt.c** will have the value 0, otherwise it will have the value 1.

This means that **pkt.c** will always be either **0** or **1**, such that the only set of values that satisfy **pkt.a==pkt.b==pkt.c** is all 1's. A similar issue is found at [link](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/how-constraint-x-y-z-evaluated)

Solution for this is, split the constraints separately as mentioned below to get the desired result.

```
if(pkt.randomize() with {pkt.a == pkt.b; pkt.b == pkt.c; pkt.c == pkt.d; pkt.d == pkt.e;})


if(pkt.randomize() with {pkt.a == pkt.b; pkt.b == pkt.c;})
```

For easier understanding and to avoid confusion maintain same print formats throughout, I have found that there is a mix of hex and decimal formats in your example

> $display("a is %h, b is %h, c is %h,d is %h, e is **%d** \n", pkt.a,
>   pkt.b, pkt.c, pkt.d, pkt.e);

Comment: But when I do just pkt.a == pkt.b , then both get same values, then why introduction of == pkt.c makes pkt.a == pkt.b constraint invalid.?

Comment: Introduction of pkt.c does not make pkt.a, pkt.b as invalid constraints, If you could observe carefully, "==" is a binary operator which results in 0 or 1 as result of evaluation which is again binary compared with pkt.c

Comment: I agree on your point, but when I simply do a constraint pkt.a == pkt.b, it always gets a and b values equal no matter what.

Comment: Due to the introduction of new constraint the simulator not able to know which one to pick and this scenario is not documented in LRM which resulted in gotchas